How to Exclude Input/Center pixel when calculating Focal Mean in Google Earth Engine JavaScript API
Context
I need to calculate a metric M based on land cover (expressed as an integrity from 1 to 100 by preprocessing) by averaging the neighborhood of each pixel in a 500m radius while excluding the input/center pixel from the average. That average will then be assigned to the input/center pixel.
What I tried
First try: img.focal_mean()
var landCover = ee.Image(...)

var M = landCover.focal_mean({radius: 500, units: 'meters'});

Based on this post, img.focal_mean() is just a shortcut for the img.reduceNeighbourhood() method. However, this does not allow me to specify to exclude the center pixel from the mean.
Second try: Multiple redcueNeighbourhoods
var landCover = ee.Image(...)

var count = landCover.reduceNeighborhood({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  kernel: ee.Kernel.circle({radius: 500, units: 'meters'})
});

var sum = landCover.reduceNeighborhood({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  kernel: ee.Kernel.circle({radius: 500, units: 'meters'})
});

count = count.subtract(1)

var MExclInputPixel = sum.divide(count)

To mathematically reproduce the behavior of excluding the center pixel from the calculation, I am thinking of:

Calculate the regular focal sum
Subtract the original land cover image from the regular focal mean image from step 1
Calculate the number of pixels in each focal window and subtract 1
Divide the image from step 2) by the image from step 3)

The question
The approach outlined in the Second try above seems long (and did not yield the expected result) and I am wondering: Is there an easy way to exclude the center/input pixel of calculating the mean through focal statistics.

Is your landCover a categorical value? If so (even if the categories are numeric) it doesn't make sense to calculate a mean.

Thanks for flagging this. It is expressed as an integrity from 1 to 100 and not categorical. I edited the question accordingly.
